# header is hidden

Tags: interface, customization

I have a few blend files that no matter how many times I quit and reopen them the header is hiding behind the other tools (I don't know what any of it is really called) but anyway as you can see below in the first image is the so-called header that you can barely make out that is hiding behind the dropdown menu that says object mode and the buttons beside it. But in the second image is just a fresh blend file I just started to show that the buttons are there but just hiding in the blend files I have made. Did I press some shortcut key I didn't know of? How do I get that row of buttons to drop below the header so I can have access to the buttons underneath it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm following the question, sometimes both of those headers are missing for me and i don't have any idea on how to make them appear or disappear. It used to be simpler in 2.7.

Comment: If you right click on the header you'll have access to a *Header* menu and you can enable the *Show Tool Settings* box, but it looks like it's not your problem here?

Comment: @moonboots, yes. The tool settings is there but it's hidden underneath the header. But thanks to your answer, I found the little arrow that allows to reveal the header if it's hidden.

Comment: I did that before you deleted the answer, and then the tools go away completely. I have to click the view button and bring the tools back, and It's still displaying them over the header.

Comment: I had this problem as well when I started using 3.0.0 (especially when I tried to mark multiple objects as assets) but it doesn't happen anymore so I thought that it is already fixed... seems it is not in your case

Answer (score 5):

Disable `Load UI` in Preferences when opening a file with an earlier version that was saved with Blender 3.0 and higher.

[image]

The elements have changed places.

[image]

When loading the new positions in older versions there are problems in the display.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't have the exact problem stated in the question but I think this should solve it since the problem is due to different Blender versions having different UI layout.

Comment: Ya, I never would have thought that the issue could be from the different blender versions.